# Google Maps update map based on if drive is active

Tags: java, android, maps

I'm making an uber clone app

this is my code and it checks if there is any drive active if so it updates the rider location

```
    if (driverActive != false) {
        LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 20));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location"));

    }
```

android studio shows a warning driverActive != false' can be simplified to 'driverActive'and it doesnt update the rider map

but if I remove driverActive if statement it works and updates the location of the rider...

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned it outs just the ParseUser functions that didn't log the anonymous user and thus making it crash because when the check function gets the info it gets nothing making driverActive null while crashing my app..

Thanks anyway